# Creating AWS SSM client with credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-ssm

I'm trying to create a SSMClient in JavaScript/TypeScript.  I've found a ton of examples but nothing seems to work.  I'm trying to get a value from the SSM parameter store.  Here is my latest:

```
    const stsClient = new STSClient({ region: REGION });

    const params = {
      RoleArn: "arn:aws:iam::425112775363:policy/SSMFullAccessCognito",
      RoleSessionName: "session1",
      DurationSeconds: 900,
    };


    //Assume Role
    const data = await stsClient.send(new AssumeRoleCommand(params));
    const rolecreds = {
      accessKeyId: data.Credentials!.AccessKeyId,
      secretAccessKey: data.Credentials!.SecretAccessKey,
      sessionToken: data.Credentials!.SessionToken,
    };

    const ssmClient = new SSMClient({ region: REGION  });

    console.info(ssmClient);
    
    const cmd = new GetParameterCommand({ Name: 'test', WithDecryption: false });

    const result = await ssmClient.send(cmd);

    console.info(result);
```

With the above it says creds are missing, which they are.  I just can't anywhere to convert "rolecreds" to Somethng SSM wants.  I can assume the role fine and I get back valid creds.

I've found 100 different ways from multiple sources but nothing works.  I'm running AWSv3.

EDIT: I am using Amplify too.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `SSMFullAccessCognito` role has the correct permissions to access the required SSM parameter, what you have to do is to pass the `rolecreds` object to the  `SSMClient`. You can do the following:

```js
const data = await stsClient.send(new AssumeRoleCommand(params));
const rolecreds = {
    accessKeyId: data.Credentials!.AccessKeyId!,
    secretAccessKey: data.Credentials!.SecretAccessKey!,
    sessionToken: data.Credentials!.SessionToken!,
};

const ssmClient = new SSMClient({ region: REGION, credentials: rolecreds });
```

Comment: That does not work:

Comment: The credentials used to sign requests.

Type '{ accessKeyId: string | undefined; secretAccessKey: string | undefined; sessionToken: string | undefined; expiration: Date | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'AwsCredentialIdentity | Provider<AwsCredentialIdentity> | undefined'.
  Type '{ accessKeyId: string | undefined; secretAccessKey: string | undefined; sessionToken: string | undefined; expiration: Date | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'AwsCredentialIdentity'.
    Types of property 'accessKeyId' are incompatible.
      Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 's

Comment: Sorry, SO only allows 500 chars.

Comment: I just commented out some code and the Assume Role is giving me Credential is missing.  How in the world is this suppose to work?  I'm trying to get to STS to get tem creds so that I can access other services.  Since this will be running via cognito I don't have the option of the aws config file, env vars, etc.

Comment: @DaveBarrineau Updated my answer, you just have to make sure that `secretAccessKey` cannot be `undefined`.

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi Thanks for the use of the non-null operator. Did not know about it. Refactoring v2 to v3 and this helped.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to actually using `roleCreds`.
If you look at the documentation for `SSMClient`, you'll see that it takes an optional credential object which you need to use in your situation: (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-ssm/interfaces/ssmclientconfig.html#credentials)

Comment: That is pretty much what the first answer is.  It doesn't work.  At runtime it gives me:

Comment: main.ts:9 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Credential is missing
Error: Credential is missing
    at SignatureV4.credentialProvider (runtimeConfig.browser.js:23:102)
    at SignatureV4.js:83:40
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3:1)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:22:1)

Comment: const awsCreds = {
      accessKeyId: data.Credentials!.AccessKeyId,
      secretAccessKey: data.Credentials!.SecretAccessKey,
      sessionToken: data.Credentials!.SessionToken,
      expiration: data.Credentials!.Expiration
    } as AwsCredentialIdentity;

  const ssmClient = new SSMClient({ region: REGION, credentials: awsCreds });

Comment: I am also having the same error. Any solution for the problem?